# Nunit console runner to test many dll's at once

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-console

I have a list of about 20 dll's that contain tests that I would like to run with the nunit.consolerunner via a Github actions on a Windows machine. Using Powershell I have created a string with all dll's and call nunit:

```
$testProjects = Get-ChildItem -Path ./Tests -Filter *Tests.dll -Recurse -Force
foreach ($project in $testProjects) {
  $projectPath = $project.FullName | Resolve-Path -Relative
  $projectList = $projectList + " """ + $projectPath + """"
}
$projectList = $projectList.Trim()
.\.nuget\nunit.consolerunner\*\tools\nunit3-console.exe --where "cat != AST" --result unittest-Results.xml --nocolor $projectList
```

However I run into the error

```
System.IO.PathTooLongException : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

--PathTooLongException
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
   at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at NUnit.Engine.TestPackage..ctor(String filePath)
   at NUnit.Engine.TestPackage..ctor(IList`1 testFiles)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleRunner.MakeTestPackage(ConsoleOptions options)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleRunner.Execute()
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Each individual dll path does not exceed this limit. However all path's combined will exceed the limit. I already added `"`'s around it to make sure not all paths where parsed as one.

Am I providing my arguments incorrectly to Nunit or is there a limitation that your combined filepaths of testfiles cannot exceed 260 characters?

If this limit exsists, would it then work if I where to make a [nunit test project](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/NUnit-Test-Projects.html)?

Comment: The stacktrace leads me to suspect that you are not passing in absolute paths. Can you check that? I'd add a loop after you trim the list to print it out, one project per line.

Comment: Correct, I'm passing in a relative path. I've reached my weekend but I'll give it a shot on Monday!

Comment: Exception is in converting relative path to absolute. It's the absolute path that's too long.

Comment: Sorry had some end of the year stuff and a vacation in between so I'm a little late. Turns out it was a mistake on my end with quotation. Using a start-process with argument list fixes it when calling nunit: `$arguments = "--where `"cat != AST`" --result unittest-Results.xml --nocolor $projectList"
        Start-Process ".\.nuget\nunit.consolerunner\*\tools\nunit3-console.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru`

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace:

$testProjects = Get-ChildItem -Path ./Tests -Filter *Tests.dll -Recurse -Force

with:

$testProjects = cmd /c dir /s/b .\Tests*.dll